# MYSQL INSERT INTO: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql, insert-into

When I run my code I get this error:

> "**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '','','','','','','')' at line 1**"

This is my code:

```
<?php
require('connect.php');

$username=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Username']);
$password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Password']);
$nome=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Nome']);
$cognome=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Cognome']);
$email=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Email']);
$città=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Città']);
$via=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Via']);
$civico=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Civico']);
$cap=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['CAP']);
$cf=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['CF']);
$telefono=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Telefono']);
$numeroCarta=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['NumeroCarta']);
$scadenza=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Scadenza']);
$cvv=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['CVV']);
$tipoCarta=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['TipoCarta']);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$flag = 0;
$query =mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE username = '".$username."'"); 
if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) { 
if($username){
     echo '<b>Username gi&agrave in uso.</b><br/>';
        echo "Torna alla  <b><a href='http://127.0.0.1//supermercato/inserimentoDati.php'>registrazione</a></b>.";
        $flag =1 ;
}
}
if ($flag == 0) {
    $query="INSERT INTO cliente(Email,Città,Via,CAP,Civico,CF,Telefono,Nome,Cognome,Password,Username,Numerocarta,Scadenza,CVV,TipoCarta) VALUES('$email','$città','$via','$cap','$civico','$cf','$telefono','$nome','$cognome,'$password','$username','$numeroCarta','$scadenza','$cvv','$tipoCarta');";


    $result=mysql_query($query);
    echo mysql_error();


if($result){
        echo "<b>Dati inseriti correttamente!</b>";
        echo "Vai al <b><a href='http://127.0.0.1//supermercato/login.php'>LOGIN</a></b>.";
        } else {
        echo "<b>Non è stato inserito nessun dato.</b><br/>";
        echo "Torna alla  <b><a href='http://127.0.0.1//supermercato/inserimentoDati.php'>registrazione</a></b>.";
}
}
}

mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried echoing your query prior to the insert? It sounds like you are going to need to escape your string. Also, you should start to look into MySQL alternatives as it has become depreciated.

Comment: Try to `print_r($_POST)` and paste here the result, it looks like some fields are empty.

Comment: echo query and run see if all param values are present. run it in phpmyadmin

Comment: cognome is missing an inverted comma

Comment: You have a missing quote `'$cognome,` change to `'$cognome'` in your `INSERT INTO cliente...`

Comment: Thank you all for your quick responses! and yes the problem was there:D

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a `'` after `cognome` You currently have

```
'$nome','$cognome,'$password',
```

should have

```
'$nome','$cognome','$password',
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response sir. This was the problem !